# How to integrate a delta distribution function by changing variable?

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta

I'm considering the integral

$$\int_0^\infty  (\frac{1}{mc})^2dp \;\delta\left[\frac{p}{mc}-\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{B}}\right]$$

If I change the variable of the $\delta$ function, such that

$$u=\frac{p}{mc}-\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{B}} $$
and
$$dp=mc\ du$$
The integral then becomes
$$\int_0^\infty  \frac{1}{mc}du \;\delta[u]$$
How do I continue from here?

Comment: A question: while $\dfrac{p}{mc}$ hasn't dimension, but $\sqrt{\dfrac{\nu}{B}}$ has, is your integral correct?

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{B}}$ also includes an arbitrary constant $a_1$ which has units of $\frac{Hz}{T}$ and $\nu$ is in $Hz$ and $B$ in $T$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change also the integration limit. Your integral becomes
$$
\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{B}}}^\infty  \frac{1}{mc}du \;\delta(u)=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{mc}\delta(u)du=\frac{1}{mc}.
$$

Comment: I understand the changing of limits, but why did you let $\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{B}} = \infty$?

Comment: Because it is a property of the $\delta$ function $\int_{-a}^a\delta(u)du=1$ and you can extend the integration interval without changing the value of the integral. This is quite common in physics.